# Maximum number of routes can Apache Camel handle

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel. I am trying to define different routes in camel. My question is what is the maximum number of routes that can be handled by Apache Camel i.e like 1000 or 2000 or 2000.

Comment: There is something very weird about your question. What do you mean how many routes? You can create as many as you server memory allows you... if you mean how many types of routes you can create...well you can check the documentation and you can even create your own custom routes. This question will probably closed since it's very unclear.

Comment: Can Apache Camel handle 2000 custom routes????

Comment: I think there is no defined limit to create routes. Creating a route is like creating an instance of a class. The question here is why would you have to create 2000 routes... this is like creating 2000 APIs

Comment: I am not creating 2000 routes. I am just creating 7 routes. While creating them I got a doubt that is there limit for routes ? I tried to Google it but I had no luck with it. So I posted here.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza I have an app that allow user to create route at system runtime using `routeBuilder`. It is possible that the number of routes reach 2000.

Comment: There is no limit in number of routes.

Comment: @hk6279 that is expected since it's dynamic... but manually creating 2K... it's pretty weird to me.